# Getting row sums for specific columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, sum, row, aggregate-functions

I created a simple dataset `df` with three columns, `Area`, `Year_2010`, `Year_2020`. The related code:

```
# Import pandas library

import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [['Netherlands', 100, 200], ['Belgium', 15, 80], ['Germany', 125, 300]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Area', 'Year_2010', 'Year_2020'])
  
# print dataframe.
df

#prints
          Area  Year_2010  Year_2020
0  Netherlands        100        200
1      Belgium         15         80
2      Germany        125        300
```

For two of the three columns (being `Year_2010` and `Year_2020`), I would like to obtain the sum of all related rows. The output of the sum should appear in a new row for both columns.

Ideally, the output reads:

```
                        Area  Year_2010  Year_2020
0                Netherlands        100        200
1                    Belgium         15         80
2                    Germany        125        300
3                                   240        580
```

However, if I apply

```
total = df.sum(axis=0)
df = df.append(total, ignore_index=True)
```

The `Area` column will also be aggregated, leading to concatenation of country names in the `Area` column:

```
                        Area  Year_2010  Year_2020
0                Netherlands        100        200
1                    Belgium         15         80
2                    Germany        125        300
3  NetherlandsBelgiumGermany        240        580
```

How can I get the row sums for specific columns, while leaving out other columns?

As an alternative to leaving the value `NetherlandsBelgiumGermany` blank, the value can be replaced by `Total`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to filter the columns by type and use indexing:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns

df.loc[len(df), cols] = df[cols].sum()
```

updated DataFrame:

```
          Area  Year_2010  Year_2020
0  Netherlands      100.0      200.0
1      Belgium       15.0       80.0
2      Germany      125.0      300.0
3          NaN      240.0      580.0
```

Alternative if you want the empty string:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns

df.loc[len(df)] = df[cols].sum().reindex(df.columns, fill_value='')
```

output:

```
          Area  Year_2010  Year_2020
0  Netherlands        100        200
1      Belgium         15         80
2      Germany        125        300
3                     240        580
```

*NB. **this assumes a range index**, if this is not the case, please update the example for alternative ways (using `pandas.concat` for example).*

Answer (score 1):

You could do that manually:

```
df.at[3, "Area"] = "" # or whatever else you want
```